# Beautiful Soup - Find identified tag in the original text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to manipulate certain text in an HTML document after I have identified the text in the **original** document. Let's say I have this HTML code

```
<div id="identifier">
    <a href="link" id="linkid">
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to delete the `id` attribute in the `<a>` tag. I can identify a particular tag using BeautifulSoup, but because it changes the formatting of the original document I can't search/replace the string either. I don't want to just write output of BeautifulSoup, instead I want to identify `<a href="link" id="linkid">` tag in the **original** document and replace with just `<a href="link">`. Any idea how to proceed?

Answering a few questions raised:

1. This is a huge existing codebase that needs some updation, so it's not just a single search/replace kind of job.
2. The original formatting is important because the organization follows a certain coding standards for formatting code, which I want to retain. Also, BS introduces extra tags for the sake of completeness like  for  and so on.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you can't just search/replace the string?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of beautifulsoup are you using?
You can edit html nodes like dictionaries in bs4

From documentation:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#changing-tag-names-and-attributes

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<b class="boldest">Extremely bold</b>')
tag = soup.b

del tag['class']
del tag['id']
```

Also, you seem to have a problem with the way beautiful soup output the modified html code.
If you want to pretty print your document, or use custom formatting, you can do it easily

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output

Comment: I am using BS4. I can delete the tag like you mentioned, but I want to replace the new tag in the original document. so in this case, I'll get "<b>Extremely bold</b>" but if original text was written as "<b class="boldest">\n\nExtremely bold\n\n</b>" it'll lose all the newlines and tabs. I hope I clarified to understand the issue.

Comment: Why is keeping them important? newlines and spaces mean nothing in HTML. Do you need them so that your document stays human readable? Also, as ASGM asked, why is it not OK to just search/replace the string without beautifulsoup

Comment: Not just human readable, but it's important to follow the formatting guidelines for the page, hence not ok. Also, I don't want to do this on all the tags, only subset of tags and have to do this in many many files.